# devexpress special sign report

Tags: mysql, sql, devexpress, report, special-characters

I have this query:

```
SELECT
   date_generator.date,sum(case when Status='Access' then 1 else 0 end) as Pass
from (
   select DATE_ADD(date_min, INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1) DAY) as `date`
   from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
   where DATE_ADD(date_min,INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN date_min AND date_max
) date_generator
```

I would like to use this query in Devexpress report, but Query editor doesnt interpretate `@i` syntax. Sign like `@` are reserved for parameters. But I need  to this syntax to dates generate.
Is anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Devexpress demand the @i variable or you can put something else?

Comment: Devexpress inretpretate @ like prefix for parameters. but this is normal query. Is working on mysql. Its imcompatible with query editor. I dont know how to solve this.

Comment: I can put something else if will works.

Comment: what kind of error does the editor show you?

Answer (score 0):

I havn't tried, but there are some static properties for sql valiation
[SqlDataSource.DisableCustomQueryValidation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.SqlDataSource.DisableCustomQueryValidation.property) and [SqlDataSource.AllowCustomSqlQueries](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.DataAccess.Sql.SqlDataSource.AllowCustomSqlQueries.property).
Please try this properties.